# phpDoc : class not "parsed"

Tags: php, oop, comments, phpdoc

I just started using phpDocumentor for the first time. When I generated the documentation, I noticed that one of my classes doesn't show up in the html documentation file.

The file is called `Authentification.class.php`. Here is the docBloc I put on top of the file :

```
<?php

    /**
     * Class Authentification
     */
    class Authentification
    {
        ...
```

I'm using [the default template](https://www.phpdoc.org/bundles/phpdocumentorwebsite/images/templates/clean.png) (I think it's called "clean").

Do you have any idea why it is not working ?

Thank you.

EDIT : So I tried to temporarily replace another class (in another file) with the `Authentification` class, and both classes didn't appear in the doc : `Authentification` still didn't show up, and the other class disappeared of course.